# Can anybody find out the error in the given sql statement?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

```
select top 1 * from database_name where nstatus='pending';
```

I am using mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.30, for Linux (x86_64) using EditLine wrapper.

When I execute the aforementioned statement I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 * from kali_node where nstatus='pending'' at line 1
```

Please tell me if I need to provide more information.

Comment: MySQL does not have a `TOP` use `ORDER BY xx DESC LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 1):

Not all database systems support the SELECT TOP clause. MySQL supports the LIMIT clause to select a limited number of records, while Oracle uses ROWNUM.

So your code should be:

```
select * from database_name where nstatus='pending' limit 1;
```